# DRYing up jquery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this, and it works fine:

```
$(document).delegate("tr.updating input, tr.updating a, tr.updating label", 'click', function(event){
```

it would be nicer, though, to not have three instances of "tr.updating" in there and instead do something along the lines of `"tr.updating (input|a|label)"`.

What's the shortest (in terms of characters in the selector) way to do this?

Comment: Why are you not using `on`?

Comment: Firstly, there's not really much you can do due to the use of `delegate()`. Secondly, `delegate()` itself is deprecated. You should be using `on()` instead.

Comment: Not sure but if your `tr` has `input,a,label,span` and you need click on first 3; you can use `'tr.updating *:not(span)'`. IMO the selector is already dried up.

Comment: Are  table rows created dynamically or are they all present at the time you install the event handlers?  Same question for the `updating` class - are they dynamic?

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, `delegate` is the best option for the version of jquery i'm using in this instance.

Comment: @MaxWilliams in which case there is nothing you can really do to DRY that up as `delegate()` (and the delegated signature of `on()`) both take the selector list as a string.

Comment: @ShaunakD inspired by your comment, i tried `$(document).delegate("tr.updating *", 'click', ...` and that's worked!  I didn't know about the * selector, or had forgotten perhaps.  If you want to turn that into an answer i'll mark it as correct, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr.updating input, tr.updating a, tr.updating label` suggests that you have elements inside `tr`.

So `*` - **[all selector](https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/)** can be used,

```
$(document).delegate("tr.updating *", 'click', function(event){
```

If the `tr` also has other elements you need to ignore, say `span`; use

```
$(document).delegate("tr.updating *:not(span)", 'click', function(event){
```

Comment: thanks.  There's actually nothing special about inputs, a's and labels, it's just that they were the things that i specifically wanted to prevent the standard click behaviour on.  * works just as well and actually caters in advance to the other things i might have forgot about :) thanks!

Comment: The all selector should not be used in production without at least specifying the child combinator selector `> *` as just `*` will select every child, of every child, possibly having catastrophic consequencs

Comment: @tic The selector was already reduced by the `tr`. I would agree with using `> *`. But *catastrophic* is exaggeration. It is just about preventing default click events.

Comment: Not necessarily exaggerated. Imagine some ajax inserted another table into  a cell on that row. You could cause a large number of selectors to be bound to, and crash/hang the page

Comment: If I would imagine I would never use jQuery. :) But my answer/suggestion fits this scenario. So there didnt seem anything catastrophic with ops html structure.

Comment: @tic - No, that's not the case.  When using `.delegate()` only one event handler is added to the `$(document)` element on this case.  It then listens for events that bubble up from children.  `*` is not inefficient in this case.  In fact, it's more efficient than using a specific selector because it's faster to evaluate when the event bubbles.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr.updating').on('click', 'input, a, label', function(e) { ...
```

Comment: If the `tr` elements are dynamically created or the `updating` class is added dynamically, this will not work, but the OPs `.delegate()` code will work.  That issue is what makes this harder.

Comment: Like @jfriend00 says i have dynamically created elements so need to use delegate.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `find`

```
$('tr.updating').find('input,a,label').click(function(e) {
});
```

or `on`

```
$('tr.updating').on('click', 'input,a,label', function(e) {
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/49z3917p/2/

Comment: `find`, in your 1st and 3rd examples, won't work because it only adds click events to the elements present on page load.  Starting the find at the document level doesn't make a difference:  the events are still added to the tr elements.  With my original code the event is on the document so catches newly added elements too.

Comment: @MaxWilliams From the jsfiddle I posted, it appears to work fine. Remove `label` from the `find` selector and now only labels will not trigger the function

Comment: I don't think your jsfiddle adds some extra rows after running the initial javascript, does it?  (which is why i need to use delegate)  Unless i'm missing something.